# How to prevent unnecessary event detection in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

How can I achieve event detection  for y>1 in the S1=... statement    only when S2 is true and otherwise prevent it since it only slows down simulation in the general case?

```
model zeroCrossingTest
// BOOLEAN VARIABLE DECLARATIONS 
Boolean S1(start=true, fixed=true);
Boolean S2(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S3(start=false, fixed=true);
Real y;
equation
der(y) = -y + 2;

// ================= 
// TRANSITIONS START 
S1 = if pre(S2) then (y>1) else 
        if pre(S1) then not ( (y>0.2)  )
 else false;

S2 = if pre(S1) then (y>0.2) else 
        if pre(S2) then not ( (y>0.5)  or  (y>1)  )
 else false;

S3 = if pre(S2) then (y>0.5) else 
        pre(S3);
end zeroCrossingTest;
```

The zero crossing from S1 = if pre(S2) then (y>1).. is still computed in OpenModelica (state event at time=0.69), although pre(S2) is false

UPDATE1: Alternative Implementation which does not generate unnecessary events.. thanks @marco

```
model zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation
  // BOOLEAN VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
  Boolean S1(start = true, fixed = true);
  Boolean S2(start = false, fixed = true);
  Boolean S3(start = false, fixed = true);
  Real y;
equation
  der(y) = -y + 2;
// =================
// TRANSITIONS START 
S1 = pre(S2) and y>1 or 
        pre(S1) and not y>0.2;
 
S2 = pre(S1) and y>0.2 or 
        pre(S2) and not ( y>0.5  or  y>1  );
 
S3 = pre(S2) and y>0.5 or 
        pre(S3);
end zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation;
```

UPDATE2: a more complex model, which gives the same behaviour of the boolean variables generates unnecessary state events (for y>0.7, y>0.8):

```
model zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation
Boolean S1(start=true, fixed=true);
Boolean S2(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S3(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S4(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S5(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S6(start=false, fixed=true);
  Real y;
equation
  der(y) = -y + 2;
// ================= 
// TRANSITIONS START 
S1 = pre(S2) and (y>1) or 
        pre(S6) and (y>0.8) or 
        pre(S1) and not ( (y>0.2)  );
 
S2 = pre(S1) and (y>0.2) or 
        pre(S2) and not ( (y>0.5)  or  (y>1)  or  (y>0.6)  );
 
S3 = pre(S2) and (y>0.5) or 
        pre(S3);

S4 = pre(S2) and (y>0.6) or 
        pre(S4) and not ( (y>0.65)  );
 
S5 = pre(S4) and (y>0.65) or 
        pre(S5) and not ( (y>0.7)  );
 
S6 = pre(S5) and (y>0.7) or 
        pre(S6) and not ( (y>0.8)  );
end zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation;
```

UPDATE 3: This implementation generates only the necessary events (2 events in total). Any reason against this approach?

```
model zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation
Boolean S1(start=true, fixed=true);
Boolean S2(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S3(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S4(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S5(start=false, fixed=true);
Boolean S6(start=false, fixed=true);

Real inS1;
Real inS2;
Real inS3;
Real inS4;
Real inS5;
Real inS6;

  Real y;
equation
  der(y) = -y + 2;
  
// ===================== 
// inState Variables 
inS1= if pre(S1) then 1 else 0;
inS2= if pre(S2) then 1 else 0;
inS3= if pre(S3) then 1 else 0;
inS4= if pre(S4) then 1 else 0;
inS5= if pre(S5) then 1 else 0;
inS6= if pre(S6) then 1 else 0;
  
// ================= 
// TRANSITIONS START 
S1 = pre(S2) and (inS2*y>1) or 
        pre(S6) and (inS6*y>0.8) or 
        pre(S1) and not ( (inS1*y>0.2)  );
 
S2 = pre(S1) and (inS1*y>0.2) or 
        pre(S2) and not ( (inS2*y>0.5)  or  (inS2*y>1)  or  (inS2*y>0.6)  );
 
S3 = pre(S2) and (inS2*y>0.5) or 
        pre(S3);

S4 = pre(S2) and (inS2*y>0.6) or 
        pre(S4) and not ( (inS4*y>0.65)  );
 
S5 = pre(S4) and (inS4*y>0.65) or 
        pre(S5) and not ( (inS5*y>0.7)  );
 
S6 = pre(S5) and (inS5*y>0.7) or 
        pre(S6) and not ( (inS6*y>0.8)  );
end zeroCrossingTest_OriginalImplementation;
```

Comment: Not really an answer, I know, but Dymola does not compute an event at 0.69s. Just to show that it seems possible to avoid the computation...

Comment: Regarding the original post and Updates 1 and 2: as Hans Olsson noted in his comment the behavior of OpenModelica is strange, as the if-then-else approach should work. I suggest to open a bug report at https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no OpenModelica expert and I don't know why S1 generates and event at 0.69s in OpenModelica (but not in Dymola, as Markus A. already noted).

But in this case the unnecessary event can be prevented by moving the `y > 1` comparison into the if condition:

```
  S1 = if pre(S2) and y > 1 then true 
       else if pre(S1) and not y > 0.2 then true 
       else false;
```

Note that I removed most braces by considering the [precedence of operators](https://modelica.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#operator-precedence-and-associativity).

You could also remove the else if branch:

```
  S1 = if pre(S2) and y > 1 or 
          pre(S1) and not y > 0.2 
       then true 
       else false;
```

Since the comparison already returns true or false, we can remove the if and simply write:

```
  S1 = pre(S2) and y > 1 or 
       pre(S1) and not y > 0.2;
```

Comment: That was exactly the first way how I implemented it and I was quite confident (although the model was more complex), that it generates events too. But now when I recheck with this simple model, you are right, this is not generating event at 0.69. Thanks

Comment: This is weird as 'and' does not guarantee short-circuit evaluation in Modelica (tools can still do it), whereas if-then-else should guarantee that the non-chosen branch isn't evaluated.